# Which type of flour would be better to use in this case?

Tags: substitutions, bread, flour

I have 450g whole wheat white flour and I would like to [bake a bread](http://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/paul_hollywoods_bloomer_84636) which needs 500g. I have also different types of flour, corn and barley flour, Which one to use for that 50g shortage of flour? Note that the shops are closed now, that's why I need to use one of flour types I have at home.

Comment: Can you give us some more detail about exactly what flours you have?

Comment: @ElendilTheTall: Sure. As I said, 450 g whole wheat flour, corn and barley flour (200 g of each).

Answer (score 3):

As you will be using whole wheat flour as opposed to the flour called for in the recipe, you won't need to choose based on preserving the original texture. I would recommend the barley flour as being most compatible with wheat flour.

Answer (score 1):

I second the barley flour since it has more protein content than the corn, and bread flours tend to favor higher protein flours.

Your WWW flour is going to be 90% of the flour content so the small 10% won't affect much overall.

Comment: Depending on the locale, the "corn flour" might not be flour at all. In the UK, that just refers to cornstarch, which is not an appropriate substitution at all. If it's actually cornmeal then it might be OK.